# Bin Counter - Increment a javascript array

Tags: javascript

I need to make a bin counter. It will be specific to my data, but as an example, I will use a grocery store. I see a lot of ways to increment items, but this would be more like counting the number of distinct entries in an SQL column (which I am not good at, either).

Say the grocery store wanted to count the number of items they sold every day through the cash register. Apples and milk are likely to have high counts at the end of the day, but the array has to be able to add elements from the inventory, even if they don't sell often.

```js
function onDataBound(e) {
    var grid = $('grid').data('kendoGrid');
    const binCounter = {};
    $.each(grid.items(), function (index, item) {
        var row = dataSource.getByUid($(item).data('uid'));
        var itemName = row.ItemName; // apples, milk, condoms, hammers, etc.
        var soldAs = row.SoldAs; // each, 6-pack, carton, dozen, case, etc.
        var itemColor = row.ItemColor;
        // help needed here
        binCounter[itemName]++;
        binCounter[soldAs]++;
        binCounter[itemColor]++;
    });
    $.each(binCounter, function (index, item) {
        console.log('binCounter[' + index + ']:');
        console.log(item);
    })
};
```

The results would have the number of `binCounter['apple']` and `binCounter['milk']` stored.

Comment: This kind of feels like you should have objects with a "name", "soldAs", and "color" properties and push that to an array of objects...`{name:"apple",index:0,[{soldAs:"each",count:0}],color:"red"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't increment a bin that hasn't been initialized yet. You have to check whether the bin exists first.

So instead of

```
binCounter[itemName]++;
```

you need

```
if (binCounter[itemName]) {
    binCounter[itemName]++;
} else {
    binCounter[itemName] = 1;
}
```

Since you need to do this repeatedly, you could write a function for it:

```
function increment_bin(binCounter, key) {
    if (binCounter[itemName]) {
        binCounter[itemName]++;
    } else {
        binCounter[itemName] = 1;
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
increment_bin(binCounter, itemName);
increment_bin(binCounter, soldAs);
increment_bin(binCounter, itemColor);
```